# Security context within FormType

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a `FormType` but I want the `FormType` to render different fields depending on the user's roles. What's the best way to do that? And how can I get the security context within a `FormType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that snippet of code into the view you want to render different fields

(where `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` is only an example)

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') %}
{% endif %}
```

Better solution, however (i.e.: securiy holes), will be to *build* the form directly into the logic, and pass only fields you're interested in

```
public function fooController() {
  //some logic here
  $sc= $this->get('security.context');
  $form = new FooForm($sc);
}
```

---

```
class FooForm extends Abstract Type
{
  private $sc;

  public function __construct($sc) {
   $this->sc = $sc;
  }

  public function BuildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, $array options) {
    if($sc->isGRanted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') {
      //add fields here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives me security problems, a field builded but not displayed can still be filled/binded isn't it?

Comment: @goto: yes, if you need that form for "security" purposes or something like that, of course you have to build it directly into business logic and pass the correct form to view

Comment: We are talking about roles, security matter even if it's not a form used for the security

Answer (score 0):

I would rather adapt the `formBuilder` in your `FormType`.

You can give him roles or variables by the `__construct()` method